# BCM2835 gpio device tree raspberry pi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-device-driver, gpio, device-tree

I was looking to modify my GPIO driver for raspberry pi using device tree support.
First there were 2 files:

1. I read the device tree file in /arc/arm/boot/dts/bcm2835.dts

and for gpio following section was present:

> gpio: gpio {
>
> ```
>                    compatible = "brcm,bcm2835-gpio";
>                    reg = <0x7e200000 0xb4>;
>                    /*
>                     * The GPIO IP block is designed for 3 banks of GPIOs.
>                      * Each bank has a GPIO interrupt for itself.
>                      * There is an overall "any bank" interrupt.
>                      * In order, these are GIC interrupts 17, 18, 19, 20.
>                      * Since the BCM2835 only has 2 banks, the 2nd bank
>                      * interrupt output appears to be mirrored onto the
>                      * 3rd bank's interrupt signal.
>                      * So, a bank0 interrupt shows up on 17, 20, and
>                      * a bank1 interrupt shows up on 18, 19, 20!
>                      */
>                     interrupts = <2 17>, <2 18>, <2 19>, <2 20>;
>                     gpio-controller;
>                     #gpio-cells = <2>;
>                     interrupt-controller;
>                     #interrupt-cells = <2>;
>             };
> ```

From the references on the internet The reg = 0x7e200000 is understood but What is 0xb4.

2. I read the device tree file in /arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2835-rpi-b.dts

and for gpio following section was present:

```
/ {
    compatible = "raspberrypi,model-b", "brcm,bcm2835";
    model = "Raspberry Pi Model B";

    memory {
            reg = <0 0x10000000>;
    };

    leds {
            compatible = "gpio-leds";

            act {
                    label = "ACT";
                    gpios = <&gpio 16 1>;
                    default-state = "keep";
                    linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
            };
    };
};

&gpio {
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&alt0 &alt3>;

    alt0: alt0 {
            brcm,pins = <0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 14 15 40 45>;
            brcm,function = <4>; /* alt0 */
    };

    alt3: alt3 {
            brcm,pins = <48 49 50 51 52 53>;
            brcm,function = <7>; /* alt3 */
    };
};
```

So, Which one of the dts files should I use, and how to read and interpret those key value pairs, for eg: what is pinctrl. and how does this approach affect on my code.

I know I am asking a lot of stuff here, but this is new and looks interesting and I want to modify my driver using this approach. Please help.

PS: I have made a driver using the standard udev support. So dynamic device node creation is managed.
I am not using platform model.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1.
**From the references on the internet The reg = 0x7e200000 is understood but What is 0xb4.**
reg = <0x7e200000 0xb4>

Here 0xb4 refers to the length of the register. 
"reg : Address and length of the register set for the device"

You can probably checkout this pdf for better info
http://events.linuxfoundation.org/sites/events/files/slides/petazzoni-device-tree-dummies.pdf

2.
**So, Which one of the dts files should I use, and how to read and interpret those key value pairs,**

I will split the question into two parts. For reading key value pairs:

Every Device tree entry would have an associated binding file that describes how you read the key value pairs.
For example http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/arm/bcm/brcm,bcm11351-cpu-method.txt . You can get the corresponding details .

Regarding which dts files should I use:

Now if u have noticed bcm2835.dtsi. is not a dts file but a dtsi file.
http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2835.dtsi

dtsi files can be included into other dts or dtsi files just like we include other libraries like conio.h. or stdio.h in our C code.

Here bcm2835-rpi-b.dts is a dts file and if u notice the file here http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/arch/arm/boot/dts/bcm2835-rpi-b.dts

it includes the following:

/include/ "bcm2835.dtsi"

This means that all the dt entries in bcm2835.dtsi is imported into bcm2835-rpi-b.dts.
You can choose to leave the nodes as is or modify the properties in rpi-b-dts, but the final entry made in dts file will be the one reflected in the dtb.

3.
**for eg: what is pinctrl. and how does this approach affect on my code.**

Pinctrl is framework provided in the kernel for accessing PIN's here gpio's. You can probably checkout the documentation used https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/pinctrl.txt